# Why don't files I delete with Dropbox's Core API get deleted on my local machine?

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I verified that the API successfully deleted the files from Dropbox by logging in to the Dropbox site. However, they remain on my local machine long after deletion.

Clicking on the icon in the menubar indicates that it is up to date, but the icon in Finder is overlayed with Dropbox's syncing icon.

In case it's relevant, I'm using the Core API's PHP SDK (v1.1.3) installed via Composer.

Comment: If the delete was successful via the API, and you can see that the file is gone via `dropbox.com`, then it sounds like the issue is in the Dropbox client. Have you tried restarting Dropbox? You may need to contact Dropbox support.

Comment: Restarting the client had no effect, but that made me think it could also be Finder (Mac OS X's file browser) or XtraFinder (an app that extends Finder), so I quit XtraFinder and relaunched Finder. The file was then gone. So maybe this is a caching issue with Finder? Either way the issue appears to not be due to anything with Dropbox. Thanks for your help.